# Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: updates

I was updating my OS from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04. I had to shutdown my laptop in between the update through internet. On restarting my laptop does not boot properly, all the applications and hardware do not function properly as also i am unable to connect to the internet. May be because the update was terminated mid way. What should i do to retrieve the OS without connecting to the internet. Or can i download the update or the programme on a USB disk and retrieve the system.

Answer (score 0):

First step I would suggest is trying to boot into [ubuntu recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

Failing that I would recommend connecting into the system with a live CD making a back up of any files you need to keep. Then go through and reinstall Ubuntu, this will allow you to keep any essential files; while making sure that you have a clean install of Ubuntu which works.